# VBA loop to copy 100 individual rows one at a time into a single row to run solver

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will copy from a list of 100 rows (9 cells each) into a single row, then run solver on it, and then copy the values to another spot in the workbook.

The below code works for one line, but everything that i have found online appears to be for paste sequential rows, not copying them and pasting them into the same row to be operated on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Sub SolverTrial()

    Range("B30:J30").Copy Range("O9")
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$2", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AA$2:$AB$2", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOptions Assumenonneg:=False
    SolverSolve (True)

    Range("AA2:AC2").Copy
    Range("N30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```vb
Sub SolverTrial()

    Dim rw As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each rw In ws.Range("B30:J129").Rows
    
        rw.Copy ws.Range("O9")
    
        SolverReset
        SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$2", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
                 ByChange:="$AA$2:$AB$2", Engine:=1, _
                 EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverOptions Assumenonneg:=False
        SolverSolve True

        'ws.Range("AA2:AC2").Copy rw.EntireRow.Columns("N")
        rw.EntireRow.Columns("N").Resize(1, 3).value = ws.Range("AA2:AC2").Value
    Next rw
   
End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome Tim, thanks very much. The only thing now is 3rd cell in the last copy function is coming back zero, how would i tell it to paste values please?